# chrome - equivalent of Visual Studio's F5 in debugging scripts

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

In Chrome, you can set breakpoints in your scripts via <kbd>F12</kbd>.  As it's stepping thru the scripts, you can hit <kbd>F10</kbd>to step over.

**Question:** How do you tell it to just continue until it hits the next breakpoint?  Similar to Visual Studio's F5 that you can hit while you're debugging your c# code.

Comment: In Chrome, I believe you have to use F8 (for steps instead of F5) and F12 (to set/remove breakpoint instead of F9). And and I think all the other keys are the same as visual studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>F8</kbd>.  For more detail, see http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html

Answer (score 2):

Press the <kbd>F8</kbd> key.